# returnだけのPHPファイルの使いかたを教えてください。

Tags: php

Laravelのコードを読んでいると、以下のようなコードがあるのですが理解できませんでした。

あるファイル内で、関数やクラスを定義せずに配列を`return`することは可能に見えます。

もしこのファイルを使用する場合にはどのようにすれば良いか教えて頂けないでしょうか。
宜しくお願い致します。

```
/config/app.php
<?php

return [

    'name' => env('APP_NAME', 'Laravel'),

];
```

Comment: ソースコード全体で`'config/app.php'`等でgrepしてみると、実際にそのコードを使用している場所が見つかるかもしれません。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ドキュメントにも書いてあるような普通の使い方ですよ。
http://php.net/manual/ja/function.include.php

```
$config = require 'config/app.php';
```